# Cannot get basic OpenGL activity working

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm following the tutorial on openGL on android developer site but when I open the activity it is just a black empty background, not a grey GL surface as expected. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

```
public class OpenGLES20Activity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);

    }

    class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{
        public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setRenderer(this);
            setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);         
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig config) 
        {
            GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        }

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused)
        {
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height)
        {
            GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because this activity is configured to show you a black background with following command. OpenGL takes colors as RGB values with each channel can range from 0.0 to 1.0.

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

change this to a color. e.g Red. and you will see red color background

```
GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: What is the fourth argument, alpha opacity? How can I get the definitions for what parameters are what in the SDK, like in VS for C# it tells you exactly what each parameter is

Comment: Yes fourth parameter is alpha value. I dont understand your next question. mostly you can refer red book or online OpenGL Spec